# Extracting href links

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wrote a python code to extract href values without https links by passing the url.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re

html_page = urllib2.urlopen("http://kteq.in/index")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    if link.get('href')==None:
       continue
    result = re.sub(r"http\S+", "", link.get('href'))
    print result
```

When I run the above code,I extracted all the href links except https links.I got the following output.

```
index
index
#
solutions#internet-of-things
solutions#online-billing-and-payment-solutions
solutions#customer-relationship-management
solutions#enterprise-mobility
solutions#enterprise-content-management
solutions#artificial-intelligence
solutions#b2b-and-b2c-web-portals
solutions#robotics
solutions#augement-reality-virtual-reality
solutions#azure
solutions#omnichannel-commerce
solutions#document-management
solutions#enterprise-extranets-and-intranets
solutions#business-intelligence
solutions#enterprise-resource-planning
services
clients
contact
#
#
#
#myCarousel
#myCarousel

#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#step1
#step2
AndroidAppDevelopment
contact
solutions
contact

index
services
#
contact
#
iOSDevelopmentServices
AndroidAppDevelopment
WindowsAppDevelopment
HybridSoftwareSolutions
CloudServices
HTML5Development
iPadAppDevelopment
services
services
services
services
services
services
contact
contact
contact
contact
contact

#
#
#
#
```

Now,I need to extract the href links which are present inside these above output links.For example,I need to extract the links inside 'index' from the above output.Please suggest me to get the output.

Comment: try scrapy which will do the same without extra code.it will automatically lookup all internal web links if you configure